# Publish Meteor Collection based on current user property

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to publish a *Collection* of sensitive information based on the *Group* a *User* belongs to.

Data example:

```
Items:
  ItemA - GroupA
  ItemB - GroupA
  ItemC - GroupB

Users:
  UserA - GroupB
  UserB - GroupA
  UserC - GroupA
```

But when I try to do

```
Meteor.publish('groupItems', function () {
  return Items.filter({ groupId : Meteor.user().profile.groupId });
}
```

It fails because I am only allowed to access the `Meteor.userId()` in such a call. (As expressed in this ambiguous error message, server side:

`Exception from sub 5jnantRJ6gyHpTkTy Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions.`

**Question:** How can I then filter the Collection based on a user property, such as `groupId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside publish, if a user is logged in, you have access to this.userId which allows you to get query the database for the rest of the user information.  So you can re-write your publish as:

```
Meteor.publish('groupItems', function () {
  if ( ! this.userId ) return [];  //return an empty array if no user is logged in.

  var user = Meteor.users.find( this.userId );
  return Items.filter({ groupId : user.profile.groupId });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for me, when changing `filter` to `find` and using `findOne` on the users. But is this performant when done on a lot of collections?